# Regular expression for parsing array indexing expressions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, regex, c++11

Am doing some semantic analysis on C++ source code. 
I have a regular expression to transform the array declarations from `int [123] [1234]` to `int [number] [number]`.

But I want the expression also be able to match dimensions such as these 
`int [i * x][ring_size][w + 6]`.

How do I tell it to match anything inside (symbols and spaces included) [ ]?

My regular expression so fas is: `regex arrayDims("\\[[0-9]+\\]");`. I am using C++11 regex header.

Thank you

Comment: I think using a regular expression approach for this is probably impossible in full generality (although I don't have a proof for that). You'll always be up against edge cases like `int[ i[3]]` for example. Lambda capture lists will also be challenging. I think you need to build a tokeniser based on the C++ grammar. Set aside a few months for that! Nothing wrong with the question though; plus one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match anything inside `[]`, then try using `\\[.+?\\]`, or something similar. The `?` turns the `*` into non-greedy. Read more on this page.

Edit: I have to note that, while this works for slightly more complex expression than just numbers, if there are more `[]` inside the expression, this will not work.

E.g. applying my pattern to `array[anotherarray[5]]` results in `[anotherarray[5]`, instead of `[anotherarray[5]]` (note the extra bracket at the end).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/546457/3495086) for more information on bracket matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match arithmetic expressions like `[w + 6]`, then you cannot do it with regular expressions. Arithmetic expressions are beyond the power of regular expressions. You have to use some kind of context-free parser.